# How to place continuous numbering on PDF?

Tags: command-line, pdf, script, pdftk

I want to place continuous numbering on a pdf document 1.5cm from the page edge.  The numbering should run from the top to bottom of every page.  This is similar to line numbering, however the numbering does not have to line with any text.

I could obviously do this manually one page at a time in a PDF editor, but it would be extremely tedious for hundreds of pages.  Not sure if there is a way to do something like this in pdftk using the command line, or alternatively a simple script?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/add-page-and-line-numbers-to-a-pdf

Comment: This is not an answer.  In that post they are trying to create line numbers that align with page text.  This over complicates things.  All I want to do is have continuous numbers going down the page with no need to align with existing text on the page.  Plus I don't want to rastersize the pdf with imagemagick etc.  I just need to find a way to directly write continuous numbering down the page.

Comment: I agree the first answer is a bit of an overkill, but the answer by scriptdolphin (create a one-page PDF with line numbers and use pdftk multistamp) should be simple and close to what you want. Will that work or were you thinking of not having the numbers reset at every page?

Comment: pdftk works great to overlay a pdf page with numbers, but the problem is the numbers need to be continuous throughout the document.  I could create continuous numbering in something like Word, but the pdf that needs overlaying with numbers has mixed page sizes and orientations.  Yes I could manually recreate the page structure in Word using blank pages, but that would be tedious for hundreds of pages.  There must be a simpler / quicker way?